# Getting Error jq: error (at <stdin>:7): Cannot index string with string "files"

Tags: json, bash, aes, jq

This is a two part process of which the goal is to take a target file and the contents of a folder and outputs a Json-formatted template store and encrypts them with AES-256. The script I am having a problem with is just the opposite.Its purpose is to take the encrypted AES-256 file, decrypt it, then take the resulting Json and break it out into the original files and text file stored within. For some reason I am getting this error though:

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:7): Cannot index string with string "files"
```

**The original bash script used to store in Json-formatted template store, and encrypt in AES-256:**

```
#!/bin/bash
#Note: This script will require an installation of jq to operate correctly
# Check whether the user has provided correct inputs
if [ "$1" = "" ] || [ "$2" = "" ]; then
        echo "Error – Please pass two parameters: a specific text document and the contents of a folder as inputs to the script"
        exit 1
fi

# Set source text document and folder name
TEXT_DOC="$1"
FOLDER="$2"

# Create an empty JSON-formatted template store
echo "{}" > template.json

# Read text document into array
IFS=$'\n'
text=("$(<$TEXT_DOC)")

# Loop through text document and populate template array
for var in "${text[@]}"; do
    key=$(echo "$var" | cut -f1 -d";")
    value=$(echo "$var" | cut -f2 -d";")
    jq --arg key "$key" --arg value "$value" '. + {($key): ($value)}' template.json > template_temp.json
    mv template_temp.json template.json
done

# Loop through folder and add it's contents to the template array
for FILE in `find $FOLDER -type f`; do
    content=$(<$FILE)
    filename=$(echo "$FILE" | cut -f2 -d"/")
    jq --arg filename "$filename" --arg content "$content" '. + {($filename): ($content)}' template.json > template_temp.json
    mv template_temp.json template.json
done

# Encrypt the template array with AES-256
openssl aes-256-cbc -a -salt -pbkdf2 -in template.json -out "${FOLDER%?}.enc"

# Remove plain text template array
rm template.json

echo "JSON-formatted template store successfully encrypted with AES-256"
```

**The troublesome script that is supposed to reverse the process:**

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
# This script will decrypt the given AES-256 encrypted file and output the contained files into the given Output_folder directory

# Read the encrypted file and store it in a variable
fileToDecrypt="$1"
outputDir="Output_folder"

# Create the output directory if it does not exist
if [ ! -d "$outputDir" ]
then
    mkdir $outputDir
fi

# Decrypt the given encrypted file and save the content in the output directory
openssl aes-256-cbc -d -a -pbkdf2 -in $fileToDecrypt -out "$outputDir/decrypted_file.json"

# Extract each file stored in the decrypted json content and save it to output directory
cat "$outputDir/decrypted_file.json" | jq -r '.[] | .files[] | "\(.name)"' | while read file ; do
    echo "Extracting decrypted_file.json to directory $outputDir"
    cp "$file" "$outputDir"
done
```

I believe that the script is successfully unencrypting it from the AES-256 format and is getting hung up on the jq command.

**The resulting Json after decrypting:**

```
{
  "fake yaml file\r": "fake yaml file\r",
  "Fakefile1.txt": "Fakecontents1=stuff1\r\nFakecontents2=stuff2\r\nFakecontents3=stuff3\r\nFakecontents4\r\nFakecontents5\r\nFakecontents6",
  "Fakefile2.txt": "Fakecontents1=stuff1\r\nFakecontents2=stuff2\r\nFakecontents3=stuff3\r\nFakecontents4\r\nFakecontents5\r\nFakecontents6",
  "Fakefile3.txt": "Fakecontents1=stuff1\r\nFakecontents2=stuff2\r\nFakecontents3=stuff3\r\nFakecontents4\r\nFakecontents5\r\nFakecontents6",
  "Fakefile4.txt": "Fakecontents1=stuff1\r\nFakecontents2=stuff2\r\nFakecontents3=stuff3\r\nFakecontents4\r\nFakecontents5\r\nFakecontents6"
}
```

**The Expected File Structure:**

```
├── Output_folder
|   └──azure-pipelines.yaml
|   └── Config-Store
│      └── Fakefile1.txt
│      └── Fakefile2.txt
│      └── Fakefile3.txt
│      └── Fakefile4.txt
```

Of course the input files were only dummy files for testing purposes. Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong? Note: I am running these scripts using Ubuntu 20.04 on Windows.

Comment: There is no `"files"` key in your decrypted json. What is your expected output after processing `decrypted_file.json` via jq?

Comment: There seem to be many other problems (or opportunities for simplification) with the script. Just to name a few: 1) don't loop text and call jq in a loop, process the full file with jq 2) your output file is overwritten in the loop and will only contain the last entry 3) UUOC (useless use of cat)

Comment: @knittl so if you can see in the "original bash script used to store in Json-formatted template store, and encrypt in AES-256:" it will show you the process. So the expected output was to provide me the same as the initial input. One targeted file lets call it azure-pipelines.yaml, and a folder, lets call it Config-Store, filled with 4 files, Fakefile1.txt, Fakefile2.txt, Fakefile3.txt, and Fakefile4.txt. I have added what the expected file structure should look like above.

Comment: But you never add the property with key "files" to your JSON, your keys are the file names ("Fakefile1.txt", etc.). `to_entries` can help to get an array of key-value pairs from an object (`{"fake.txt":"content"} | to_entries` will output `[{"key":"fake.txt","value":"content"}]`.

Comment: (jq doesn't know that those keys were files once. `.files[]` means that there has to be `"files"` as literal key in your JSON document somewhere; that's not the case currently)

Comment: @knittl -  Thank you. I grabbed this code from a suggested source, and admittedly dont know very much about how it works. I am currently going back to basics and going to do my best to reconstruct the basic idea from scratch.